# Drawing thousands of lines in WebGL or Canvas

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, webgl

I am trying to draw thousands of lines between nodes, and the line positions are constantly changing (i.e. consider a node being dragged while connected to thousands of children by these lines).

Below is a simplified example of an issue I have. When drawing several thousands of lines in WebGL or Canvas, the rendering takes a long time (up to a second or more). For each line that needs to be updated, I clear the `PIXI.Graphics` object and then redraw it from scratch.

I was wondering if there is a way to improve this by batching the draw to WebGL somehow. Ideally the render time could be reduced significantly, so I could draw up to 100,000 lines in less than a second.

**Warning:** It may crash your browser tab - lower the number of objects to below 20,000 if this happens.

```js
var container = new PIXI.Container(),
    i,
    renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(1000, 1000);
renderer.backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF;
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
for (i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
    line = new PIXI.Graphics();
    line.lineStyle(1, 0x888888, 1);
    line.moveTo(0,0);
    line.lineTo(10*i,1000);
    container.addChild(line);
}
renderer.render(container);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/3.0.8/pixi.js"></script>
```

Pure JavaScript/WebGL/Canvas improvements are useful as well (Pixi is not required).

Comment: There's no good way now.
Pixi only support continued lines.
like:
lineTo(x,y);
lineTo(x2,y2);
....
And moveTo will make a new graphicData. And I don't see any code about merge lines graphicData. @ratchet freak, If you're right, please show me the PIXI's merge line segments code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a first step instead of 20k graphics objects containing each a single line use a single graphics object and put the 20k lines in it

```js
var container = new PIXI.Container(),
    i,
    renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(1000, 1000);
renderer.backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF;
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

line = new PIXI.Graphics();
line.lineStyle(1, 0x888888, 1);
for (i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    line.moveTo(0,0);
    line.lineTo(10*i,1000);
}
container.addChild(line);

renderer.render(container);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/3.0.8/pixi.js"></script>
```

PIXI will then batch all those lines into a single buffer and draw it using a single draw Elements command.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this approach earlier this morning as well but didn't realize how significant the benefit would be. I didn't realize PIXI controlled the buffer per `PIXI.Graphics` object (still very new to the library).